# Problem running QGIS r.horizon command in PowerShell

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, powershell

I would to run this command in images below via CMD also without opening QGIS GUI on Windows 10

I added "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.2\bin\qgis_process-qgis.bat" to PATH then run my command into QGIS to be sure that everything is okay, the algorithm run until end with expected result without problems, I copied the command from QGIS then closed QGIS and paste that copied command in PowerShell them it doesn't work (see below the images).

The copied command:

```
qgis_process-qgis.bat run grass7:r.horizon --distance_units=meters --area_units=m2 --ellipsoid=EPSG:7030 --elevation='C:/Users/admin/Downloads/OpenTopography/Biggest_LB_SRTMGL3.tif' --step=10 --start=0 --end=360 --distance=1 ---d=true ---c=true --output='C:\Users\admin\Downloads\tempo' --GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER='35.000000000,37.000000000,33.000000000,35.000000000 [EPSG:4326]' --GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER=0
```

I changed only `qgis_process` to `qgis_process-qgis.bat`, I am running QGIS 3.8.28 (Firenze) on Windows 10

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The PATH is for **directories** -- The `.bat` file doesn't belong in the PATH, just the parent directory.

Comment: Can you try replacing the single quotes with double quotes?

Comment: @Vince, that doesn't help

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca, thank you that worked

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca I answered my own question but I found it somehow not respectful so please answer it you by yourself

Comment: After finished the algorithm, the result as expected but also at end 'output: C:\Users\admin\Downloads\tempo
QTemporaryDir: Unable to remove "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\QGIS3-AXyZiE" most likely due to the presence of read-only files.
QTemporaryDir: Unable to remove "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\QGIS3-EglmEr" most likely due to the presence of read-only files.' 
is it so bad?

Comment: @Khaled, you are welcome. I answered the question based on what I understand. If you want to investigate more on the subject and add sources that support what is written, feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.2\bin" is already in the PATH enviroment variable, so there is no need to add it again.

I am not very good at executing commands in the Windows Power Shell, but the error indicates that the space between the coordinates and the reference system was not considered within the parameter, which is a character string.
On GNU/Linux systems both single and double quotes can be used in the terminal to define a string of characters. But on Windows it seems to be mandatory that only double quotes can be used for that purpose.

Regarding the error that the files in the temporary directory could not be deleted, there is nothing to worry about. Its removal will be part of some regular maintenance task when the machine is rebooted.